# Yii how to send through ajaxButton the selected value of a combo?

Tags: ajax, yii

```
 echo CHtml::ajaxButton (Yii::t('Listing.Listing','Associa'), 
                    $this->createUrl('listing/addAssociation', array("id" => $model->id, "itemId"=> '5'  ) ), 
                    array('update' => '#dataToUpdate')
                    );
```

i'm using this example code (and it's working), to send an id and an itemId ('5' fixed in the example), to addAssociation.

All is working, but I've the need to pass for itemId the result of a jQuery expression. something like

```
"itemId" = "js: $('#myDropDown option:selected').val();"
```

But in this case, the js expression is not evaluated and in actionAddAssociation i see that itemId is the literal string:

```
 "js: $('#myDropDown option:selected').val();"
```

**how to allow an user to select a combo, and the pass the selected value to an action based on this action ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass that in the [ajax option's `data` property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```php
echo CHtml::ajaxButton (Yii::t('Listing.Listing','Associa'), 
    $this->createUrl('listing/addAssociation', array("id" => $model->id)), 
    array(// these are ajax options
        'data' => array('itemId'=> 'js: $("#myDropDown option:selected").val()'),
              // and don't use semi-colon after val(), you can also pass id here itself
        'update' => '#dataToUpdate'
    )
);
```

Comment: I agree this one is more straight and simple way.

Comment: But can you explain where Yii evaluates this JavaScript expression and how passes the result to ajax request?

Comment: @Ezze yes, it is simpler, thanx. How this happens is clear if you look at the call sequence, which is: CHtml::ajaxButton()->button()->clientChange()->ajax()->CJavaScript::encode()

Comment: Thank you so much, now I see that `CJavaScript::encode` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jQuery's [ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/) to add a function that will alter your data being passed through ajax.

First, you have to register the following script on your page's initialization:

```
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (originalOptions['data'] && originalOptions['data']['requestId'] === "myDropDown") {
        delete originalOptions['data']['requestId'];
        originalOptions['data']['itemId'] = jQuery("#myDropDown option:selected").val();
        options['data'] = jQuery.param(originalOptions['data']);
    }
});
```

Here `options` is a complete `settings` object determined for [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I pass an additional `requestId` parameter to identify ajax request and, to make things simplier, a view could look like this:

```
<?php
print CHtml::dropDownList("myDropDown", 1, array(
    1 => "First",
    2 => "Second",
    3 => "Third"
));
print CHtml::ajaxButton(Yii::t("Listing.Listing", "Associa"), Yii::app()->createUrl("listing/addAssociation"), array(
    'data' => array(
        'requestId' => "myDropDown",
        'id' => $model->id
    ),
    'update' => "#dataToUpdate"
));
```